# I am running a IBM runtime estimator job. Is there anyway to retrieve the job position of the submitted job using Session?

Tags: qiskit-runtime

I am running an Estimator job using Session on an actual backend.

```
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Estimator, Session, Options

with Session(service=service, backend=backend) as session:
    estimator = Estimator(session=session, options=options)
    job = estimator.run(circuit, observable, shots=1)
    print(f">>> Job ID: {job.job_id()}")
    print(f">>> Job Status: {job.status()}")
```

The following code prints the total number of jobs in queue.

```
status = backend.status()
jobs_in_queue = status.pending_jobs

service.jobs(backend_name=backend)
print(jobs_in_queue)
```

And `job.status()` outputs the status.

Is there a way to get the position of the job in the queue? Something similar to https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/0.19/qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.QueueInfo.

I am aware of this issue: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues/7865
I have commented on this thread asking for solution as well.

Thanks in advance.